# For U.S. history 1800-1830, what was GDP by sector and industry?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, economy, antebelllum

The U.S. Census Bureau's Historical Statistics of the United States does not appear to break GDP down.

I'm aware that the terminology is imprecise:

1. GDP is a modern term, but is *much shorter* than the contemporary understanding, "What was the total value of goods and services produced by sector?"
2. "Industry" is also an imprecise term, but is *much clearer* than "what was the total value of goods and services produced in agriculture, craft, finance, and other sectors including nascent industrial activity".

Comment: Industry seldom existed outside of the UK at this time.

Comment: The concept of GDP as we use it today [didn't even really exist until the 20th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product#History). Most likely anyone wanting that exact information broken down that exact way is going to have to do a ton of research to compile it from other sources. You might luck out and find someone else has already done that for you, I suppose. However, I'm thinking it might be better to ask what kind of financial information of that ilk *is* available. What exactly are you looking to see or compare?

Comment: See [The Economic Growth of the United States, 1790–1860, Prentice Hall, 1961.](https://www.amazon.com/Economic-Growth-United-States-1790-1860/dp/0393003469). It has a ton of info about how the US economy was organized. Cotton was the biggest, of course. Selling food from the North Midwest to the slave owners in the south was second.

Comment: I'm very reluctant to close a question when @axsvl77 has provided a legitimate answer.  (Hey Axsvl77, can you move that to an answer). I'll grant you that the term "GDP" is an anachronism, but the British Empire was calculating the value of goods and services imported & exported by colony from an early period. I think the _question_ is excellent.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I've also seen industrial age countries compared by tonnage of production of particular goods, which was useful enough for the purpose it was being put to. Based on the edit, I think that information in an answer would be welcome?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thanks! Unfortunately, I won't have time to dig that book out of my closet to give a substantive answer. The data exists though

Comment: @Bregalad  Modern industry with factories and steam powered machines might have hardly existed outside of the UK at this time, but industry in the sense of a sector of the economy like the fishing industry, for example, existed.  Historians are always writing about medieval industries or ancient Roman industries.

Comment: @MAGolding most of those industrious activities didn't produce "value" as we understand it.  Correspondingly with the slow development of the concept of the political economy as opposed to the domestic economy or a moral economy.  For some crazy reason between 1700 and 1900 human conducts around social reproduction changed dramatically, and the meaningful ways of talking about them changed dramatically.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this source (page 70)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.825.5578&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the shares of labor devoted to "industry" in the U.S. economy were 11.9% in 1800, 14.9% in 1810, 19.0% in 1820, and 20.0% in 1830, with the remainder devoted to agriculture.

'"Industrialization" was only getting started in the first half of the 19th century, but picked up greatly in the second half.